# How to Mock a HttpServletRequest that is not the input of filter method

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, mockito

```
Class Permission implements ContainerRequestContext
{

    @context
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException 
    {
        String Path=servletRequest.getPathInfo();

        int id=containerRequestContext.getId();

        if(id==null){
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(new ServerResponse(ExceptionUtil.getErrorMessageObject(...),errorCode,new Header<Object>()));
        }
    }
}
```

How to write the Test for the filter method. I am able to mock the ContainerReqeustContext. But how to mock the HttpServletRequest since it is not the input of the `filter()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@InjectMocks` annotation:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class Test {

   @InjectMocks
   private Permission permission;
   @Mock
   private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
       permission.filter(...);
   }
}
```

Or you can use a simply setter.

```
Class Permission implements ContainerRequestContext
{
    @context
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException 
    {
          ...
    }

   void setHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
     this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
   {
}

 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 class Test {

     private Permission permission = new Permission();
     @Mock
     private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

     @Test
     public void test()
     {
        permission.setHttpServletRequest(servletRequest);
        permission.filter(...);
     }
  }
```